# How to write jQuery inside PHP Function?

Tags: php, forms

i want to show 'error' and styling the input form errors.

this my code so far :

this index.html :

```
 <div class="error" style="display:none"><ol></ol></div>
    <input name="name">
    <input name="number">
```

and this one process.php:

```
<?php



$a   =$_POST['name'];
$b   =$_POST['number'];

if(empty($a)) {
  echo
   "<script>
   $(document).ready(function (){
   $('.error').slideDown();
   $('.error ol').append('<li>Name Cannot Empty</li>');
   $('input[name=\'name\']').css({"border":"1px solid red"});
   });
   </script>";
}

    ?>
```

its not working on my code, i dont have idea why.

Comment: Well the problem is the unescapped double quotes, as the SO syntax highlighter makes obvious. More important though is why you would want to do this

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP string is delimited by `"` characters.

Your JavaScript includes `"` characters.

You need to escape them: `\"`.

---

Alternatively, stop trying to write JavaScript embedded in HTML embedded in PHP. It's hard to read and causes problems like you are experiencing:

```
if(empty($a)) {
    ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $('.error').slideDown();
                $('.error ol').append('<li>Name Cannot Empty</li>');
                $('input[name="name"]').css({"border":"1px solid red"});
            });
        </script>";
    <?php
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape double-quotes `"` using backslash `\` => `\"`:

```
if(empty($a)) {
  echo
   "<script>
   $(document).ready(function (){
   $('.error').slideDown();
   $('.error ol').append('<li>Name Cannot Empty</li>');
   $('input[name=\'name\']').css({\"border\":\"1px solid red\"});
   });
   </script>";
}
```

Comment: this working form me, thanks guys for feedback.
[CASE CLOSED]

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[name=\'name\']').css({"border":"1px solid red"});`

this line causing isse.. here double quotes around border and its value terminate the string here.. use the single quotes here..